# Using Matlab, how can I group rows by year into a structure?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, structure

Using Matlab, I am trying to build a structure that will store grouped rows of matrix X organized by year.  The vector yrsStr has each year which will need to be grouped by.  Please refer to matrix X for the values I am trying to group:

```
yrsStr = [734139 734504 734869 735235];
% 734139 is Jan 1 2010
% 734504 is Jan 1 2011
% 734869 is Jan 1 2012
% 735235 is Jan 1 2013

X = [734500 0 1 2 3;
    734502 4 5 6 7;
    734504 8 9 10 11; % Jan 1 2011
    734505 12 13 14 15;
    734868 16 17 18 19;
    734869 20 21 22 23; % Jan 1 2012
    734872 24 25 26 27;
    735234 28 29 30 31;    
    735235 32 33 34 35; % Jan 1 2013
    735236 36 37 38 39;
    735250 40 41 42 43];
```

For example, if the date is less than Jan 1, 2011, then each row with dates less than 734504 (Jan 1, 2011) will be stored in a matrix which will then be stored in struct(1).data.  Struct(1).year will simply be Jan 1, 2010.  For all dates >= 734594 (Jan 1 2011) and < 734869 (Jan 1 2012), each row will be stored in a matrix and which will then be stored in struct(2).data.  Struct(2).year will simply be Jan 1, 2011.  The same will be applied for the remaining rows.  All values in yrsStr and X will constantly changing (including additional or even less years) so I am trying to write the code to be as dynamic as possible.  I started writing the following code, but I have run into a wall and really don't have an idea how to finish or continue.  The following code doesn't do much yet but it only reflects my brainstorming.

```
tDay = datevec(date)
numYrs = 3;
%Compute date vectors for previous years for comparison
for i=1:1:numYrs+1
    if i == 1
        yrs(:,:,i) = [tDay(1,1) tDay(1,2)-tDay(1,2)+1 tDay(1,3)-tDay(1,3)+1 0 0 0];
    else
        yrs(:,:,i) =  [yrs(1,1,1)-i+1 1 1 0 0 0];
    end
end

%Convert date from vector form to serial
jj = size(yrs(1,1,:));
for j=1:1:jj(3)
    yrsStr(1,j) = datenum(yrs(:,:,j))
end
yrsStr = fliplr(yrsStr); %ascending serial numbers

% ###########I DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO DO BELOW HERE###############

kk = 1; %initialize yrsStr counting
m = 1; %initialize Y
for k=1:1:size(X,1)
    if  X(k,1) < yrsStr(kk)
        Y(m) = X(k,:);
        m = m + 1;
    elseif X(k) < yrsStr(kk)
        testStruct(kk).year = yrsStr(kk);
        testStruct(kk).
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to how I can proceed, please advise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not loop free, but close enough I guess.

```
for ii = 1:length(yrsStr)-1
  struct(ii).data = X(X(:,1) >= yrsStr(ii) & X(:,1) < yrsStr(ii+1),:);
end
struct(length(yrsStr)).data = X(X(:,1) >= yrsStr(length(yrsStr)),:);
```

I can't think of a faster way of doing the last line. (Except using `if`, or adding a term in the end of `yrsStr` with a big number, and make the loop go an extra step.

The last one would be:

```
yrsStr(end+1) = inf;
for ii = 1:length(yrsStr)-1
  struct(ii).data = X(X(:,1) >= yrsStr(ii) & X(:,1) < yrsStr(ii+1),:);
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: WOW. That was fast.  Thank you very much!